# More Optimal solution for Recursion

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I coded an DP problem few days back and i want to reduce my recursive solution to more optimal solution, i.e. reducing multiple calling of same function again and again

n<10^9 and k<10^3

```
long long fibo(long long n,long long k){
    if(n==k){
       return 2;
    }
    else if(k==1){
       return 2*n; 
    }
    else if(k==0){
       return 1;
    }
    else if(k==2){
       return 2*(n-1)*(n-1);
    }
    else {
       return (fibo(n-1,k) + fibo(n-2,k-1) + fibo(n-1,k-1));
    }
}
```

Iterative approach

```
long long fibo[1010][1010]={-1};
long long fib(long long n,long long k){
     if(n==k){
       return 2;
      }
    else if(k==1){
      return 2*n;
      }

    else if(k==0){
      return 0;
     }
    else if(k==2){
      return 2*(n-1)*(n-1);
     }

   if(fibo[n][k]!=-1){
       return fibo[n][k];
      }
  else {
      return  fibo[n][k]= (fib(n-1,k) + fib(n-2,k-1) + fib(n-1,k-1));
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** I added result of my performance test and rough mathematical estimation of `fibo(n, k)`.

---

### My Answer

> i want to reduce my recursive solution to more optimal solution

The following code is my answer.
This code is implemented by Dynamic Programing.
Details of the algorithm is explained in the below.
Matching test with your original code is [**here**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uzHC9RUhDUtkndLa) and a performance test is [**here**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GlU5RPOKL0blyssE). Performance is well improved. Calcuation time of `fibo(40, 10)` is as follows:

> Original : 24 691 879 microsecond ( ~ 24 second)
>
> DP. ver. : 33 microsecond

```
long long fibo_DP(long long n, long long k)
{
    if(k<0 || n<k){
        throw std::logic_error("Value of fibo is ill-defined for (k<0 || n<k).");
    }
    
    // boundary
    if(n==k){
        return 2;
    }
    else if(k==1){
        return 2*n; 
    }
    else if(k==0){
        return 1;
    }
    else if(k==2){
        return 2*(n-1)*(n-1);
    }
    
    std::vector<long long> memo(k+2, 2); // diagonal line.
    
    const auto n_last = (n-k);
    for(auto i = 1U; i<=n_last; ++i)
    {
        // modifying first two values
        memo[0] = 1;       // (i  ,0)
        memo[1] = 2*(i+1); // (i+1,1)

        // throwing away the value of (k, k) by sliding
        for(auto l = memo.size()-2; l>3U; --l){
            memo[l] = memo[l-1];
        }

        // interrupting the value of (i+2, 2)
        memo[3] = 2*(i+1)*(i+1);
        
        // do local updates.
        for(auto j = 4U; j<memo.size(); ++j)
        {
            const auto sum = memo[j-2] + memo[j-1] + memo[j];

            memo[j-2] = memo[j-1];
            memo[j-1] = memo[j];
            memo[j]   = sum;
        }
    }
         
    return memo.back();    
}
```

---

### Well-definedness of Our Problem

**First of all, I think that this problem is well-defined if and only if `k>=0 && n>=k`.**
In order to clarify, consider the 2-dimensinal matrix where the value at `(n, k)` is equal to `fibo(n, k)`.
Then your sequential sum

```
return (fibo(n-1,k) + fibo(n-2,k-1) + fibo(n-1,k-1));
```

is represented by the following diagram:

[image: summation]

To terminate this sum, we need an upper boundary and a left boundary where initial values are given.
OTOH, the initial values are defined only for `n==k`, `k==0, 1, 2`, blue boxes on the following picture:

[image: regions]

If `(n, k)` is located on the region (1) where `n<k`, the above sequential summation becomes an infinite loop because the upper boundary is not given.
And if `(n, k)` is located on the region (2) where `k<0 && n>=k`, it again becomes an infinite loop because the left boundary is not given.
Thus `fibo(n, k)` is well-defined if and only if `k>=0 && n>=k` and
**we assume `k>=0 && n>=k` in the below discussion.**

---

### Details of This Algorithm

Going back to the first summation diagram, we can find the following algorithm in calculating `fibo(n, k)`.
First, we construct an array which has `k+2` elements (1,0), (2,1), **(2,2)**, **(3,2)**, **(3,3)**, (4,4), (5,5)… (k, k), black boxes on the following picture:

[image: initial state]

Next, we start our recursive summation by following manner.
Black boxes are again `k+2` elements stored in our array in each step.
This process is local one and would be performance effective from the view point of the memory access:

[image: update]

If we have calculated (k+1, k), we have the values of (1,0), (2,1), **(3,2)**, **(4,3)**, **(5,4)**, **(6,5)**, …, **(k, k-1)**, (k, k), **(k+1, k)** in our array.
Then we go to the next diagonal parallel line.
Modifying first two values of our array, interrupting the value of (4,2) at the fourth element, throwing away the value of (k, k), we construct the next initial array, **(2, 0)**, **(3, 1)**, (3, 2), **(4, 2)**, (4, 3), (5, 4), …, (k-1, k-2), **(k, k-1)**, (k+1,k).

[image: next]

Here again we start the sequential summation with the previous manner.

Repeating this process, finally we get the value of `fibo(n, k)`.

---

### Mathematics and Rough Estimation

For `fibo(k+1, k)` with `k>=3`, we get the following recursion equation:

[image: k+1_recursion]

We can solve this equation and get the following result:

[image: k+1_formula]

Next, for `fibo(k+2, k)` with `k>=3`, we get the following recursion equation:

[image: k+2_recursion]

We can again solve this equation and get the following result:

[image: k+2_formula]

In this manner, we can estimate the order of `fibo(k+p,k)` as `k^p`,
that is `fibo(n,k) ~ k^(n-k)`.
**Thus, unfortunately, `n~10^9 and k~10^3` is tooo large for `long long` and meaningless values would be returned.**

Comment: @ for larger values of n and k like 100000000 and  9 , the code is working very slow . any help will be appreciated

Comment: To begin with, if  n and k like 100000000 and 9, then `fibo(n,k)~ 9^999999991` as I wrote which is out of range of long long 2^64-1. Thus it is difficult to calculate `fibo(100000000, 9)`.

Comment: so it won't work for larger values of n and k then . any suggestion should i change my approach ?

Comment: It seems to be quite difficult to store precise values of order 9^999999991 on most present day hardware. I have currently no idea.

Comment: Hi @alkagoswami, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.